# Is it possible to make zcat output text even if it's uncompressed?

Tags: pipe, cat, gzip

The problem is I have some database dumps which are either compressed or in plain text. There is no difference in file extension etc. Using `zcat` on uncompressed files produces an error instead of the output.

Is there maybe another `cat` sort of tool that is smart enough to detect what type of input it gets?

Comment: What file extension are they? Is there any way I could get some examples to play around with?

Comment: Just use `zcat` on only the compressed dumps.

Comment: Yea, but I don't know which ones are compressed without manually checking, some of them are *.gz some not and that is the problem. May I rephrase the question, how to check if file is gzipped ? and use that information in next command ?

Comment: @rsk82 But you just said they all have the same extension.. So you mean they all have .gz but only some of those are actually compressed? The others are just plain text?

Comment: Well - that sounds like your problem. Whatever system you've setup that provides that kind of output needs revising. In the meantime, GNU `grep` can be instructed what to do if it encounters a binary type file - and that might make a good filter for the cleanup.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add the `-f` option.

```
$ echo foo | tee file | gzip > file.gz
$ zcat file file.gz
gzip: file: not in gzip format
foo
$ zcat -f file file.gz
foo
foo
```

(use `gzip -dcf` instead of `zcat -f` if your `zcat` is not the GNU (or GNU-emulated like in modern BSDs) one and only knows about `.Z` files).

Comment: One correction: you need the `c` parameter for `gzip` to get the output to stdout: `gzip -cdf`. But `zcat -f` works also fine in Mac OS if you use stdin: `zcat -f < file`.

Comment: Addendum: by using stdin `zcat` can only take one argument which kind of defeats the purpose of `cat`, so I think using `gzip` is the best solution (in fact `zcat` is just a hardlink to `gzip` but it seems to be more picky about the file extension when called as `zcat` in Mac OS).

Answer (score 10):

One portable, simple suggestion would be to use `zgrep` instead of `zcat`, and just use a search pattern that matches every line.

```
zgrep $ some-file
```

Unlike `zcat`, `zgrep` will happily handle uncompressed files.  From man zgrep:

```
zgrep - search possibly compressed files for a regular expression
```

Comment: What do you mean by *portable*? If you mean that it can be installed and used on any system then isn't is as portable as any other?

Comment: I mean that zcat and zgrep are normally packaged together, so this ought to work anywhere where zcat was available to begin with.  And it's agnostic to the particular shell being used - ought to work fine in bash, zsh, and even csh or Solaris's non-POSIX bourne /bin/sh.

Comment: Oh, cool. I noticed I had both - but I didn't know they came together. Thanks. You've got my vote.

Comment: `zgrep` is a script that wraps around `gzip` and `grep`. The reason it works with uncompressed data is because [it passes the `-f` option to `gzip`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131944/22565)

Comment: Also note that as far as portability goes, `zcat` was first only dealing with `.Z` files. GNU came up with `gzip` and the `gz` format later and its gzip/zcat handles both `.Z` and `.gz` files. You'll probably still find commercial Unices where `zcat` knows nothing about gz files.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `gzip` you can do `zcat file 2> /dev/null || cat file`. This is not POSIX-standard, and does not work on BSD `gzip`, you really should fix your system so that all `gzip`ped files have the `.gz` extension (of course plain text files may have any extension, including `.gz`).

Comment: You should add an `|| { echo "$filename" ; cat $file ; } >&2` to cat to keep the out streams separate so the asker can more easily clean up the mess. I mean - well, I hope that's clear enough.... But this is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add my conclusion from the comments as an answer, I think the best most compatible way is to use

```
gzip -cdf [ name ... ]
```

This is also how `zless` and `zgrep` do it internally.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in Bash:

```
for filename in *;do #Replace with your actual loop
    case $filename in
    *.gz) gunzip <"$filename";;
    *)    cat "$filename";;
    esac
done
```